# Android studio and Gradle Plugin - Error while creating a new project

Tags: android, ide, gradle

I receive this error while trying to create a new project with Android Studio.
Windows 7 Ultimate 32Bit with last version of JDK and Android SDK 22

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm23p.png

What I do?

Comment: Perhaps don't use preview software if you don't have the experience to work around the bugs?

Comment: I have tried everything and can not be. on another PC works perfectly on my other hand, should not be